# Can't get variables to update with new values conditionally

Tags: javascript, variables, webpack, scope

I thought this will be straight-forward but I am missing something.
I have an array of images contained in a variable which works fine, but I want it to change the value of that array conditionally at certain viewport breakpoints.

Problem is when I do this it seems fine (No error in the console), but the images aren't updated.
Here is the original code:

```
function showBg() {
    // Randomize bg
// morning
    let morningArray = ['sunset-view-of-mountains-733100.jpg', 'purple-petal-flower-surrounded-by-green-plants-during-66288.jpg', 'time-lapse-photography-of-waterfalls-during-sunset-210186.jpg', 'two-cargo-ships-sailing-near-city-2144905.jpg'];
    let morningBg = morningArray[Math.floor(Math.random() * morningArray.length)];
    let morningPath = './src/img/hero/';
    let morning = morningPath + morningBg

    // afternoon
   let afternoonArray = ['empty-dining-tables-and-chairs-1579739.jpg', 'brown-and-green-mountain-view-photo-842711.jpg', 'photo-of-keyboard-near-mouse-3184460.jpg', 'america-arid-bushes-california-221148.jpg'];
    let afternoonBg = afternoonArray[Math.floor(Math.random() * afternoonArray.length)];
    let afternoonPath = './src/img/hero/';
    let afternoon = afternoonPath + afternoonBg;

    // evening
    let eveningArray = [ 'twisted-building-during-nighttime-1470405.jpg', 'beautiful-beauty-blue-bright-414612.jpg', 'landscape-photo-of-mountain-with-polar-lights-1434608.jpg', 'photo-of-toronto-cityscape-at-night-2478248.jpg'];
    let eveningBg = eveningArray[Math.floor(Math.random() * eveningArray.length)];
    let eveningPath = './src/img/hero/';
    let evening = eveningPath + eveningBg;
    console.log('two', eveningArray)

  if (window.matchMedia("(max-width:1024px)").matches) {
                    eveningArray = ['Talon.png'];
                    console.log(eveningArray)
                }

  showBg()
}
```

I also used this format for the matchMedia conditionals:

```
 function tabQuery(x) {
            if (x.matches) {
             const tabArray = ['Talon.png']
                eveningArray = tabArray;
                console.log(eveningArray)
            }
            }
            const x = window.matchMedia('(max-width:1024px)');
            tabQuery(x)
            x.addListener(tabQuery);
            console.log(x)
```

Still did not work. The variable is still using the original array
Lastly I tried instantiating the variable outside the function and updating it in the function. I got the same results, the matchMedia array doesn't work

```
let eveningArray;

// and

  eveningArray = [ 'twisted-building-during-nighttime-1470405.jpg', 'beautiful-beauty-blue-bright-414612.jpg', 'landscape-photo-of-mountain-with-polar-lights-1434608.jpg', 'photo-of-toronto-cityscape-at-night-2478248.jpg'];
```

What am I doing wrong?
How can I solve this, I have the medium and small size of all images, that's why I am trying to do the matchMedia functionality.

I did a very minimalist version on js fiddle which surprisingly worked like a charm 
link here [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Alara_Stealth/7sbx3y4p/30/)
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, guys, this is very funny, but I stumbled upon the answer while working on the minimalist version on js fiddle.

it turns out that the conditional was placed in the wrong place when you take into consideration code hierarchy.

it's a conditional, hence it should come immediately after the original declaration. so that after it is set, all other logic can be added to it.

```
// evening
    let eveningArray = [ 'twisted-building-during-nighttime-1470405.jpg', 'beautiful-beauty-blue-bright-414612.jpg', 'landscape-photo-of-mountain-with-polar-lights-1434608.jpg', 'photo-of-toronto-cityscape-at-night-2478248.jpg'];

    if (window.matchMedia("(max-width:1024px)").matches) {
        eveningArray = ['Talon.png'];
        console.log(eveningArray)
    }

    let eveningBg = eveningArray[Math.floor(Math.random() * eveningArray.length)];
    let eveningPath = './src/img/hero/';
    let evening = eveningPath + eveningBg;
    console.log('two', eveningArray)
```

This way the array is updated conditionally and then all the logic below will be added. formally, it was just being made "code on its own, with no required logic added".

Also if you have better explanations or a way I could make this a simple function that will work for all cases (morning, afternoon and evening), so as to keep the code dry.
 I will very much appreciate it 
I do not really consider this as an answer completely, I still want your input.